# According to Catholic sources, what is the "Leviathan" in the Bible?

Tags: catholicism

According to Catholic sources<sup>1</sup>, what is the [*Leviathan*](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=Leviathan&qs_version=RSVCE) in the Bible?

Is it a mythical creature or a particular animal that it can be identified with or some other creature?

<sup>1. E.g. Catholic Biblical commentary, Church Fathers, saints, etc. *The best answer will reference these.*</sup>

---

cf. [Leviathan and Behemoth - JewishEncyclopedia.com](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9841-leviathan-and-behemoth).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01517a.htm):

> **LEVIATHAN.** — The word Leviathan (Hebrew, *líweyãthãn*), which occurs six
>   times in the Hebrew Bible, seems to have puzzled not a little all
>   ancient translators. The [D.V.](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05140a.htm) has kept this name, Job 3:8; 40:20;
>   Isaiah 27:1; it is rendered by dragon Psalm 73:14, and 103:26; The
>   word leviathan means:
>
> - (1) crocodile (Job 40:20 and Psalm 73:14);
> - (2) a sea-monster (Psalm 103:26, Isaiah 27:1);
> - (3) possibly the Draco constellation (Job 3:8).

In Haydock's [commentary on Job 40](http://haydock1859.tripod.com/id1091.html), he says much the same thing; in Job 40 the reference is to the crocodile, but the reference could also be a whale or dragon. [Thomas Aquinas](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/SSJob.htm#403) says it is "some great fish" but could also be a reference to the devil. The devil reference is supported by Haydock's [commentary on Job 3](http://haydock1859.tripod.com/id1054.html), in which he says:

> The fathers generally understand the devil to be thus designated.
>   Septuagint, "he who is about to seize the great whale," (Haydock) or
>   fish, which they also explain of the conflict of Satan with Jesus
>   Christ. (Origen, &c.)

Footnote to Job [40:25], [Job, chapter 40 | USCCB](http://usccb.org/bible/job/40:25#22040025-1) (New American Bible) has: **Leviathan**: *although identified by some scholars as the crocodile, it is more likely another chaos monster* and the Jerusalem Bible Popular Edition footnote to Job 3:8 has: *The dragon of primeval chaos; he might be roused by a curse against the present order.*

Clearly, there is no consensus within or without Catholicism on what *exactly* the leviathan is. But they seem to agree it is a large aquatic or semi-aquatic beast or a chaos monster, and possibly a reference to the devil.